# Parent innerHTML and child nodes

Tags: javascript, html

I want to ask if I want to remove an HTML element's children but I don't necessarily want to loop through them, would setting the parent's `ìnnerHTML` to null or an empty string remove the children **from memory**, not just from the visual part of the document?

Comment: Yes, overwriting an element’s `innerHTML` property achieves basically the same as removing the child nodes one by one – they will be “deleted” in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will completely remove children.
For example, you have:

```
<div id="a_div">
<input type='button'><br>
<img src='image.png'>
</div>
```

Then

```
document.getElementById("a_div").innerHTML="<input type='button'><br><img src='image.png'>";
```

So if you set innerHTML to `""` (`document.getElementById("a_div").innerHTML="";`), then `a_div` will be

```
<div id="a_div">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then `empty()` function used on the parent element will remove the elements from the DOM.

Comment: I'm not using jquery :/

Comment: well yes it does remove the elements from the DOM. I tried it here http://jsfiddle.net/UzT37/